# MongoDb mongoose deprecation warning {useUnifiedTopology: true} but it is already set to true

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, deprecation-warning

when i trying to connect mongoDb using mongoose deprecation warning appears

i add option to the code but stil warning is there

```
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(process.env.DB_CONNECTION,
 {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser:true });
```

it appears
{useUnifiedTopology: true} warning only

Answer (score 0):

another package in your app might connect to mongodb that is why you are still getting that error. In may case, I have a logger to log the errors to mongodb:

```
export const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: "info",
  format: winston.format.json(),
  defaultMeta: { service: "user-service" },
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: "error.log", level: "error" }),
    new MongoDB.MongoDB({ db: process.env.DB_URI! }),
    // new winston.transports.
  ],
});
```

so this line `new MongoDB.MongoDB({ db: process.env.DB_URI! })` is causing the warning still logged on the terminal. When I comment this line out, I do not get the warning anymore. If you want to see the source of the warning, add `--trace-deprecation`  to the start script in package.json.

```
 "start":"node -r dotenv/config --trace-deprecation  dist/bundle.js"
```

Comment: is there any other  piece of code in your app connecting to mongo.